# JSON encoding with Services_JSON and json_encode in PHP returning empty object with jQuery ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax/get_rule.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {                 
                    feature : feature,
                    ajax : 1
                },
                success: function(resp) {
                    console.log('in here');
                    console.log('response: ' + resp);

                },
                error : function() {
                    console.log('there was an error...');
                }
            });
```

I am using the PHP PEAR [Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198) class to encode my array into a JSON string and then echo that out in the response, like this:

```
echo Registry('json')->encode(array('ajax' => 1, 'feature' => 'rfc1872'));
exit;
```

In the above example `Registry('json')` is a `Services_JSON` object.

I have also tried the PHP built-in function `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode(array('ajax' => 1, 'feature' => 'rfc1872'));
exit;
```

Neither of these work and although I don't fall into the error callback in the jQuery ajax call above I get a response value of `response: [object Object]` with an empty object in Firebug.

Why would I not receive a response back to my jQuery code with a JSON-encoded string?

Comment: How do you know it's empty? I don't see you logging it to the console. `console.log('response: ' + resp);` will convert the object to a string first, and the default string representation of an object is `"[object Object]"`, no matter whether it has properties or not. What does `console.log(resp);` show you? If you didn't get JSON as response, the success callback would not even be executed I believe.

Comment: Oh gawd, that's exactly what it was. I changed `console.log('response: ' + resp);` to `console.log(resp);` as you advised and the object pulls through correct. Many thanks, can you submit as an answer and i'll happily accept. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Felix King has provided in the comment above this is caused by, effectively, casting the `resp` to a string with:

```
console.log('response: ' + resp)
```

Changing to:

```
console.log(resp);
```

solved the problem.